# Unexpected error when trying to connect to database in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, windows-7, database-connection, visual-web-developer

**The problem:**

In Visual Studio 2010 Professional I choose Server Explorer and right-click on Data Connections to choose "Add Connection". Then I get this error:

> An unexpected error occurred in the
>   .NET Framework Data Provider for
>   Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5.
>   Please contact the provider vendor to
>   resolve this problem.

**My enviroment:**

- Windows 7 SP1
- Visual Studio 2010 Professional (trial version)
- SQL Server 2008 R2 Express

**I've tried**

- Installing Visual Web Developer Express (gives the same problem)
- Reinstall of VS 2010 Professional
- Reinstall of Sql Server 2008 R2 Express
- Tools => Import and Export Setting => Reset all Settings
- Run: Devenv.exe /ResetSkipPkgs

**Comments**

Maybe the registry is messed up in some way. 
One post:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vstsstart/thread/b6f7fc36-5a34-4166-9e75-7ac39993182b

says that I should modify the registry at
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\DataProviders

But I don't even have a folder named DataProviders in the 9.0 (or 10.0) folder. So maybe that's a problem.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started "add and remove programs" and removed everything that was named something about "Visual Studio". Then I reinstalled Visual Studio 2010 Professional. And now it works!

Comment: Uninstall everything linked with Visual Studio! Wow, that Microsoft at 100%. The beautiful thing about that is probably just one registry key that is missing and you must reinstall Visual Studio just fix it. For me, the error is about Oracle. The driver of oracle seems not installed correctly. I just uninstalled the ODP.Net and then reinstalled it again and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the same and use the VS 2010 uninstall utility to remove everything, then reinstall it all.  This was caused by ODP for .Net which didn't install properly and I could not connect to data sources and basically meant I could not edit the dataset file!